# Javascript Cart

Tags: javascript, simplecart

I'm using SimpleCart JS for a project I'm currently working on, but I have a few glitches.

When I attempt to remove an item from the cart, it does absolutely nothing... There is documentation for SimpleCart but i assumed it would work as default functionality?

Where or how i do enitiate a remove.item(); function?

Documentation is available here: http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/simplecart-item-remove

```
simpleCart({
// array representing the format and columns of the cart,
// see the cart columns documentation

cartColumns: [
    { attr: "name" , label: "" } ,
    { attr: "quantity" , label: "" } ,
    { view:'remove', label: '' } ,
    { attr: "price" , label: "", view: 'currency' }

],
```

I hope i asked this question clear enough! Thank's again.

Comment: If you don't have a reference to the item you want to remove, you'll have to get a reference to it first, e.g. [`simpleCart.find`](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/simplecart-find) will give you an _Array_ (from which you probably want item at index `0`).

Comment: Example? This really isn't my expert field lol Just want to get this hickup out the way so i can move onto the next bit.